# What is the best way to perform soft delete in Graph database?

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune, property-graph

What is the best way of implementing soft delete with timestamps( start date and end date) in Graph database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's fairly straightforward to blind a traversal based on a timestamp. Take this example graph were "ts" is a mock timestamp represented as a long:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','alice').as('a').
......1>   addV('person').property('name','bob').as('b').
......2>   addV('person').property('name','claire').as('c').
......3>   addE('interacted').property('ts', 125).from('a').to('b').
......4>   addE('interacted').property('ts', 126).from('a').to('b').
......5>   addE('interacted').property('ts', 127).from('a').to('b').
......6>   addE('interacted').property('ts', 126).from('b').to('c').
......7>   addE('interacted').property('ts', 150).from('b').to('c').
......8>   addE('interacted').property('ts', 151).from('a').to('b').iterate()
```

You can simply write your Gremlin to account for the "ts":

```
gremlin> yesterday = 130
==>130
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','alice').
......1>   outE('interacted').has('ts',gt(yesterday)).inV().
......2>   values('name')
==>bob
```

Depending on the complexity of your requirements, adding this filter on "ts" may get burdensome and clutter your code. If that is the case, it's possible that `SubgraphStrategy` might help:

```
gremlin> sg = g.withStrategies(SubgraphStrategy.build().edges(has('ts',gt(yesterday))).create())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:3 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> sg.V().has('person','name','alice').out('interacted').values('name')
==>bob
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','alice').out('interacted').values('name')
==>bob
==>bob
==>bob
==>bob
```

Comment: One word of warning on this based on experience is that soft-deleted edges and vertices can cause performance issues because they still must be considered via .has('ts',gt(yesterday)) and that is not free.  When looking at many edges/vertices, it can add up. I've seen instances where 20% of the query time was simply trying to filter out the soft-deleted stuff.  A traditional relational database can easily index items out based on a deleted timestamp, but a graph traversal must consider the edge to see if it's deleted.